# How to connect to Samba share on an ASUS router

Tags: networking, samba, asus

New UBUNTU user, Ver 18.04 LTS on ASUS F555D Laptop.  My ASUS router has a 4Tb Samba Share which has all my domestic data on it.

Using the native "files" application I can see the share and all of its contents.  The files application shows the Windows share on the router (RTAC68U-D208) as a button at the top it doesn't show the first folder of the share (HOME) but then shows all the subsequent folders.

When you click on a sub directory it pops up a dialog box which asks for the following Connect As Anonymous or Registered User, Username, Domain and Password etc.

If you fill it out with the appropriate info and click "Connect" it greys out but nothing happens.

Can a clever user explain in kiddy language how to connect my share so I can get on with my work and learn to use this wonderful Windoze alternative

Answer (score 2):

The Samba world would be in a much better place if we would all use updated software. These NAS devices all seem to be a generation behind.

Run a test. Open your terminal and run the following command - replacing XXX with the name of your router or its ip address:

```
smbclient -L XXX
```

Do you get the following error:

> Server does not support EXTENDED_SECURITY but 'client use spnego = yes
>   and 'client ntlmv2 auth = yes'

Note: You may have to install a package first because Ubuntu 18.04 does not have an smb.conf file by default:

```
sudo apt install smbclient
```

If you do then edit smb.conf:

```
gedit admin:///etc/samba/smb.conf
```

And right under the workgroup = WORKGROUP line add the following two lines:

```
client use spnego = no
client ntlmv2 auth = no
```

THe reason why a CIFS mount as suggested by Gin Gon is a better solution is that you can "dumb down" the CIFS mount specific to your one device without altering smb.conf to dumb it down for all connections in your file manager.

Comment: This worked for me for Asus router RT-N14UHP. Note that the two parameters to be added are deprecated and "yes" will be enforced for them in future versions. https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#CLIENTUSESPNEGO

Answer (score 0):

There is already [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide) on how to accomplish this.

Please see the "**Connecting using CIFS**" section.

Comment: Thanks,  Given my lack of experience with Ubuntu, this is presently bey0nd my capabilities.  Am I correct in saying that you cant use files to mount and connect to the drive?